# Adding Google Authentication to my Non-MVC Application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth, google-api, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net Web Forms Application. It's not MVC, this seems to be an important distinction. It uses Individual Authentication. Everything seems to work fine up to the point that `http://localhost:888/signin-google` is called. Then, nothing. I'm thinking that something is supposed to get stored to my `AspNetUserLogins` table, and that I should have been logged in to my site.

My question: Clearly, I’ve missed something. What do I need to fix to allow my users authenticate with their Google ID?

**What I’ve tried**

- I’ve created a blank, new ASP.NET Web Forms application to
  determine if I’ve altered any of the OAuth/OWin code. I get the
  same problem.
- I’ve added Facebook authentication to my application. It
  works fine. Click `Login with Facebook` button. Moments later, I’m logged in.
- In `Web.config` changed `authentication mode` from `Forms` to `None`.

**What I’ve read**

- I read [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) straight from the template that Visual
  Studio 2015 generated for me. All it says is to comment out
  `UseGoogleAuthentication()` which I’ve done and filled in with
  my Client ID and Client Secret.
- I’ve also read [this helpful article](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application) to no avail.
- I’ve read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072786/google-authentication-using-owin-oauth-in-mvc5-not-hitting-externallogincallback), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964139/googleoauth2-issue-getting-internal-server-500-error/23595862#23595862), and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096734/c-sharp-4-asp-net-non-mvc-custom-authentication) post here, however they deal
  with MVC constructs which are absent in my Web Forms application.

**What Happens**

- I login with Facebook, and my application behaves as though I’m
  an autnenticated user. I note a Facebook record in `AspNetUserLogins`.
- I login with Google, I get so far as a callback to `signin-google` then straight back to my login page with no authentication.
- I trace through my code, the call to `GetExternalLoginInfo()` in the 
  `Page_Load` method of `RegisterExternalLogin.aspx` is returning `null`. I’ve read several articles from the Google search
  results for "[GetExternalLoginInfo returns null](https://www.google.com/search?q=GetExternalLoginInfo%20returns%20null)" again to no avail.
- If I type `http://localhost:888/signin-google` directly into my
  browser, I get a blank page. Not a 404, just a blank page. I see in
  my browser history, a reference to `signin-google` that contains
  evidence that this page was involved in a callback (e.g., `state=`
  querystring params).

I see the following entries in my server log (edited for clarity)

```
2015-11-22 06:25:12 ::1 GET /signin-google state=***&code=****&authuser=0&session_state=****&prompt=none 888 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+...+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:888/Account/Login 302 0 0 228
2015-11-22 06:25:12 ::1 GET /Account/RegisterExternalLogin providerName=Google&returnUrl=&error=access_denied 888 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+...+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:888/Account/Login 302 0 0 112
```

**My Code**

In Startup.Auth.cs, added to method `ConfigureAuth`

```
GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions googleAuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google.ClientId" ],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google.ClientSecret"],

    // the rest of this per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964139/googleoauth2-issue-getting-internal-server-500-error/23595862#23595862
    //CallbackPath = new PathString( "/Callbacks/Google" ),

    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", context.User.GetValue("picture").ToString()));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("profile", context.User.GetValue("profile").ToString()));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
};

googleAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleAuthenticationOptions);
```

Comment: I have solved my problem. Removint the two lines `context.Identity.AddClaim` fixed it. Once I have a firm grasp on the why of it all, I will post my answer.